# php implode function empty array is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the values in array from query and i converted array values in string by using implode until then its working fine,

So after that i passed that implode variable in another where condition query in select box so what happened now is if the array is empty the select boxes are disappearing can anyone help me how to solve that one..

**here is my code**

```
<select name="course1id" class="form-control" required> 
                            <?php
                            $r = array();
                            $query = "SELECT course1id,course2id FROM mdl_course_relation";
                            $result = $DB->get_records_sql($query);
                            foreach ($result as $res) {

                                $r[] = $res->course1id;
                                $r[] = $res->course2id;

                            }


                            $courseids = implode(",", $r);
                            //$where = '';

                            //if (sizeof($r))

                                //$where .= 'AND id NOT IN($courseids)';

                            ?> 


                            <?php
                            $sql = "select id,fullname from {course} WHERE id!=1 AND id NOT IN($courseids)";


                            $courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
                            ?> 

                            <option value="">Choose Course</option> 
                            <?php
                            if (sizeof($courses)): foreach ($courses as $row):
                                    $coursename = $row->fullname;
                                    ?> 
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row->id . '|' . $row->fullname; ?>"><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></option> 
                                    <?php
                                endforeach;
                            endif;

                            ?> 
                        </select>
```

Comment: if your array is empty then your query execution will fails. add not in if array is not empty.

Comment: where i have to add that.can you please explain it

Comment: Since you are always excluding course id 1, you can also add 1 to the array of $r.  This will never break your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to check for empty array

Update the code like this

```
$courseids = implode(",", $r);
$where = '';

if (count($r)>0)
{
    $where = "AND id NOT IN($courseids)";
}
$sql = "select id,fullname from {course} WHERE id!=1 $where";
$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

Comment: your logic is working if there is no courses linked  drop downs is coming fine..but if there is courses linked  drop downs are not coming

Comment: even i got the same issue when  i try to use sizeof and i tried with array_filter too its not  working

Comment: $where = "AND id NOT IN($courseids)"; here replace single quote to double quote